# Size of displayed equations in html file produced by htlatex

Tags: htlatex

I am using htlatex to produce a html file from a latex file, with no particular config file. It works relatively well except for the following problems.

Loading the html file in Chrome android on my phone, I get tiny displayed equations in portrait mode, see the screenshot (when I rotate in landscape mode, the equations look fine).

Also, a $\sum$ symbol is replaced by the letter P, and it happens also for integrals.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add minimal working example? Especially with the wrong sum symbol. The wrong size of images happens only in chrome on android?

Comment: Hello, it seems the problem with the sum symbol comes from the fact that I was using \usepackage{yhmath}. Without this package, the sum symbol appears correctly. And yes, the wrong size of images seems to be related to chrome on android. With chrome on my desktop, things are fine.

Comment: Ah, it seems that we don't have any specific configuration files for `yhmath` package. But I still get the correct symbol. You may try to change the way math is created. Try the following commands: `make4ht file.tex "mathjax"` or `make4ht file.tex "mathml,mathjax"`.

Comment: The package yhmath was not really needed in my file so it's not a problem to remove it. Adding "mathjax" does not seem to change things much. With "mathml", math formulas are lost for some reason. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe you use an old TeX distribution? Mathjax should work